# ionic 2 with strophe not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, ionic2

I am currently trying to use strophe with ionic 2, I have npm both `strophe` and `jquery` and also `@types/strophe` and typings.

this is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Strophe} from 'strophe';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {


  public connection: any ;

  public BOSH_SERVICE: any="http://52.32.***.5:5280/http-bind/" ;


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}


login() {


  this.connection = new Strophe.Connection(this.BOSH_SERVICE);
  this.connection.connect('ama****'+'@'+'localhost', 'o***oop', this.onConnect);

  console.log("Hello World !");

 }



onConnect(status) {
  console.log('onConnect: '+status);
}
```

when I try ionic serve I get this error

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_strophe__.Strophe is undefined
Stack trace:
HomePage.prototype.login@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55747:9
View_HomePage_0/<@ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:135:21
viewDef/handleEvent@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12170:98
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13462:39
debugHandleEvent@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13050:12
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9070:12
renderEventHandlerClosure/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9662:20
decoratePreventDefault/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:33505:53
f</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9644
                                                                                                                                                                 NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@htt           p://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4397:28
f</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9557
c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4812
t/this.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10626
```

Comment: I think you need to install [strophe.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strophe.js) the other one seems deprecated

Comment: Npm strophe includes strophe.js in the node modules it's new version 1.2.4 not depreciated but made for npm and node exclusively.

Comment: ah ok.. my bad.. it mentioned deprecated in the command line when I checked it from npm

Comment: I don't know maybe your right but it's the only one they have in npm.

Comment: Looks like a namespace is defined https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/strophe/index.d.ts try `import * as Strophe from 'strophe'`

Comment: very kind of you to look into it suraj but still a diffrent error when i try it    Module '"strophe"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
src/pages/home/home.ts
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as Strophe from 'strophe';
@Component({

Answer (score 2):

1) download Strophe library from Strophe [Site](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)

Then, You should put the framework inside /src/assets/

Then, You should add the script tag to the index.html before polyfills.js and main.js

Thus

```
<script src="assets/strophejs-1.2.14/strophe.js"></script>
```

Last,

you should put this declare statement before to use the strophe.

```
declare var Strophe: any;
```

It works for me!

2) another way is you can install using

```
npm install strophe.js
```

and copy strophe.js file from node_modules/strophe.js folder to your src/assets folder as above and then give path in your index file